# You have not registered any clients with the Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I registered in https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ to use instagram api to crawl instagram public pages for my research on face but I got "You have not registered any clients with the Instagram API" and I didn't get any access token or client id
what should I do?